# What is the origin of the word "cocktail"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

I am familiar with the word "cocktail", meaning *a mixture*, and in particular, a mixed drink.  But I'm unable to find any useful information about its origins.  The Shorter OED simply says, "*origin obscure*".

Is there any evidence of early use and/or influences on the formation of the word?

Please include dates with your references, so that answers can be easily compared.

Comment: One supposed etymology is that the drinks were once served with a feather sticking out, sort of how one might use a cocktail umbrella.

Comment: Toby, Did you try to google for "cocktail etymology" ? That gives me lots of articles including the etymonline.com one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cocktail (n.)** (from [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cocktail))

> "First attested 1806; H.L. Mencken lists seven versions of its origin,
>   perhaps the most durable traces it to French [coquetier](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=coquetier&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&imgil=1Jh_On-sEcnExM%253A%253B7BQdyD8TBpvJVM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.pinterest.com%25252FLesrevesdevero%25252Fcoquetier%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=1Jh_On-sEcnExM%253A%252C7BQdyD8TBpvJVM%252C_&usg=__pbhIcbYjdyA61dECVOCAj2T_x_o%3D&biw=1024&bih=657&ved=0ahUKEwjMge-N0tjSAhWDopQKHU2-CUQQyjcINA&ei=CkXJWMzUH4PF0gTN_KagBA#imgrc=1Jh_On-sEcnExM:) "egg-cup"
>   (15c.; in English cocktay). In New Orleans, c. 1795, Antoine Amédée
>   Peychaud, an apothecary (and inventor of Peychaud bitters) held
>   Masonic social gatherings at his pharmacy, where he mixed brandy
>   toddies with his own bitters and served them in an egg-cup. On this
>   theory, the drink took the name of the cup. Used from 1920s of any mix
>   of substances (fruit, Molotov). Cocktail party first attested 1928".

Comment: Some references https://books.google.com/books?id=h5igQMFsCtUC&pg=PA25&dq=%22Drank+a+glass+of+cocktail%22+%22found+Burnham%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirw6CH09jSAhVJNiYKHcHRBjYQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Drank%20a%20glass%20of%20cocktail%22%20%22found%20Burnham%22&f=false say there was an earlier use of the word in the 28 April 1803 newspaper The Farmer's Cabinet (Amherst, NH). http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025526/holdings/